# How to add new worker node at run time of Apache Flink cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to setup apache Flink cluster with multiple machine, And just want to know if my Flink cluster is up and running and at run time i want to add new worker node to faster the computation work. How i can do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a new Task Manager ? https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/cluster_setup.html#adding-jobmanagertaskmanager-instances-to-a-cluster

Comment: yes new TaskManager as an Worker. will be new instance can join to cluster as worker? what is command to add it.

Comment: ```bin/taskmanager.sh start``` But first you need to configure your Task Manager.

Comment: Can you explain with example. suppose I have existing worker 192.0.0.12 and I want to add new worker 192.0.0.15. How i can proceed in this case.

Comment: The answer varies depending on whether this is a standalone cluster, or yarn, or kubernetes.

Comment: I am working for standalone cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You would manually trigger a savepoint, shut down your cluster, reconfigure it for the new machine, start it again, and then restore from the savepoint. During the restore, the state would be re-distributed based on the new (higher) parallelism of your beefier cluster.